# Django implement the chain method and list

Tags: django, list, chain

I'm trying to do a join between two models (tabels: Reports and Sources) such as explained in the following code.

In statistics.html I don't see data as I would.

I'm newbie in DJANGO

**View.py**

```
from itertools import chain
class Statistics(ListView):
    model = Reports
    template_name = 'statistics.html'  
    context_object_name = 'Statistics' 

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Statistics, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['statisticsTest'] = list(chain(Reports.objects.values('id','idsite','idcity','idsys',
                                            ).filter(idsite = self.kwargs['idsite'], 
        idcity = self.kwargs['idcity'],
        idsys  = self.kwargs['idsys'],
        ), Sources.objects.values('idsite','idcity','idsys','name_site','name_sys').filter(idsys =self.kwargs['idsys'])))
        return context
```

**statistics.html**

```
  counter:{{statisticsTest|length}}
    {% for item in statisticsTest %}
    <p>{{ item.idsite }}</p>
    <p>{{ item.idsys }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

    {% for item in statisticsTest %}
        {{ item.idsite }}
        {{ item.idcity }}
        {{ item.idsys }}
        {{ item.name_site }}
        {{ item.name_sys }}

    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Exactly what do you see, and how is it different from what you expect?

Comment: What's your `context['statisticsTest']`? Can you give the result of `statisticTest`?

Comment: I need to see the fields of Reports Table (two rows  in this case) and the field of Sources Table (one row) in separate template zone, but I see the fields of THREE rows

Comment: @seuling my context contains one queryset Empty and one with my feld values that is: QuerySet [<Reports: Reports object>....], 'Statistics:'[{'idsite':..,'idcity':..,etc. }}

Comment: Then what exactly you want to show in the template? I don't know why you use `list` and `chain`. Can you update your model and what fields you want to show? I think you just can use `get_queryset()` in `ListView`.